# Can a Jew follow another religion's dietary laws?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, gentiles, food

Suppose another religion has dietary laws that overlap with those of Judaism. For example, Zoroastrianism prohibits eating all land animals and prohibits eating various kinds of fish and other sea animals depending on conditions such as the species, what time of year it is, and how the animal was raised. Also they are prohibited from eating all insects and have to wash and inspect all fruits and vegetables to make sure there is no bugs in them, also they are strictly prohibited from eating pork just like in Jewish dietary laws https://authenticgathazoroastrianism.org/2012/03/05/zoroastrian-dietary-laws-animal-friendship-and-stewardship/

Would a Jew be allowed to follow such dietary laws, along with the Jewish dietary laws?

Comment: It is forbidden to imitate the customs of gentiles. This would be included.

Comment: Jews do not avoid meat during this time. Furthermore, mitzvot are to be performed with proper intention. Avoiding even non kosher food with the intention of serving a foreign deity is prohibited, and one would not get "credit" for the mitzvah.

Comment: Will the Jew eat items that are forbidden by Jewish law? Or will the Jew just not eat some items that are permitted by Jewish law?

Comment: ywnmoderator, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I've edited the question to broaden it and remove what seems to me to be extraneous details about Zoroastrianism that distract from the core question. Please [edit] further if you feel that the question now doesn't reflect what you want to know about Judaism.

Comment: Why would one want to do this?

Comment: It would depend on one's motive

Comment: @ShamanSTK If the religion imitates the diet first given by God to mankind, such as being vegetarian, then it's not a gentile custom.

Comment: @DoubleAA Zoroastrian dietary laws predate _kashrut_

Comment: @daniel So what?

Comment: @aaron why must that be true?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because then it's not a gentile practice, it's an everyone practice.

Comment: @aaron but the intent is to follow a gentiles practice. Perhaps that matters. Without any indication that you are applying the traditional halakhic rules of this prohibition and not just making assumptions based on translated prohibition titles, your claims aren't super valuable

Comment: @DoubleAA If the intent is to follow a genuine practice given by God in the Torah, it is not a gentile practice. Even if the gentiles have adopted it themselves. At least, that's the opinion of Abraham ben Rambam. If one knows that being vegetarian or vegan was an acceptable practice given by God through our Torah, then one may adopt that practice, with that knowledge, even if it is also the practice of the gentiles around oneself

Comment: @Aaron "If the intent is to follow a genuine practice given by God in the Torah" That doesn't seem to be the case here at all (even assuming that vegetarianism is such a practice).

Answer (score 3):

The Torah writes (Vayikra [20:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0))

> You shall not follow the practices of the nation that I am driving out
>   before you. For it is because they did all these things that I
>   abhorred them

Writes the [Sefer HaChinuch 262](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.262.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> [...] **And the law is the same for all the nations**, since the matter is
>   that they turn away from [following] God, and worship idolatry. And
>   the content of the commandment is that **we not behave like them in** our
>   clothing and **our matters**. [...] It is from the roots of the
>   commandment [that it is] in order to distance ourselves from them and
>   disparage **all of their customs**, and even in dress.

As such one cannot follow the customs of another people/religion if the objective is to do like them. It is particularly true if one would decide not to eat permitted *kosher* foods (e.g., beef) because Zoroastrianism prohibits it.

For more see [here](https://torah.org/learning/halacha-overview-chapter4/) and [there](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/236234/halachically-speaking-following-the-customs-of-the-goyim.html).

Comment: At the same time, if someone Jewish avoids beef today because of health reasons, that's perfectly fine. No one is forcing you to eat it. It's trying to observe another faith that gets tricky. Meanwhile, there are plenty of foods that are certified by multiple religious authorities; the fact that something is also halal doesn't make it any less kosher. Maimonides ruled 800 years ago that we prefer to not intentionally have a cow face Mecca before it is slaughtered, but if that's a requirement in a Muslim land, the meat is still kosher if slaughtered properly by a Jew.